# Which version of Grails support JDK 8?

Tags: java, maven, grails

I am using following configuration for Grails :

- Grails version 2.4.0
- Maven version 3.2.5
- JDK version 1.8.0_51

When I run the server, I am getting two errors. In my POM, I am using `grail-gorm` and `grail-crud` dependencies. I am not able to get these dependencies from Maven repository. Can you please all suggest me what should I do o that I am able to run Grails on jdk 8?

Comment: Try  with JDK 7 and see if you get the same errors.

Comment: What errors are you getting exactly?  What does your pom look like?

Comment: getting issue for these two jars. but when I use jdk 7 and grail version 1.3.7 then its working. but I need to run it on JDK 8

Comment: Its showing like not able to download jar from maven using these pom . Look like these jar not supportive for grails 2.4.0 is there any way to do that ?

Comment: Check the `BuildConfig.groovy` that has the settings for the target/source level. It should be like `grails.project.target.level = 1.8` and
`grails.project.source.level = 1.8`. However, they are re-generated by default in a new grails project.

Comment: @user3614970 - See my answer below and go for it. It will work for you. :)

Comment: where I can find this file  BuildConfig.groovy ?

Comment: @user3614970 - This is at `conf` folder of your application. However, you can still get problems if you continue using `1.8.0_51` with that grails version. So I recommend that you switch to my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93472/discussion-between-user3614970-and-my-god).

Answer (score 2):

Version `1.8.0_40`, `1.8.0_45` and `1.8.0_51` has breaking updates with grails.

Grails is natively supported in `1.8.0_25`, `1.8.0_31`.

Once you get the compatible java versions, just clean the grails project, mark the entries in the environment variables correctly and then you are good to go.

Check this: [java-archive-javase8-2177648.html#jdk-8u25-oth-JPR](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html#jdk-8u25-oth-JPR).

Comment: I am using JDK 1.8.0_25 and grails version 2.4.0 but its still not running. Its asking me to use maven 3.1.0.
when I used maven 3.1.0 then its showing error related to 

org/grails/grails-crud/2.4.0/grails-crud-2.4.0.pom
org/grails/grails-gorm/2.4.0/grails-gorm-2.4.0.pom

Failed to execute goal on project admin: Could not resolve dependencies for project

Comment: Took me a while to find it, direct link to 31 - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html#jdk-8u31-oth-JPR