# Changes not auto reloaded in controllers

Tags: grails

I created a fersh grails app with **2.4.3** and **Java 1.8.0_91** and created a simple controller with index action.

Did some changes in build config as :

```
grails.reload.enabled = true
grails.project.fork = [
        test: false,
        run: false,
]
```

and run the app using the command:

```
grails clean;grails compile; grails run-app -reloading
```

application is running perfectly, now I did some changes in the controlles index action but that changes were not reloaded.

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure but downgrade java version to 7 or less.

Answer (score 0):

Grails 2.4.3 is not compatible with the Java 8 version you are using. You have to use other or Java 7 instead. 
[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33364145/which-version-of-grails-support-jdk-8)

Comment: I have an legacy project which is using 2.4.3 and Java8 and I did not have any issues runnig 2.4.3 with java8. I just was confirming via creation of fresh poject -reloading functionality which is not working in my legacy as well as newly created app.

Comment: That is a part of the tomcat configuration that runs over that java version